# Forming n digit numbers out of 1,2,...,9 such that k digits can repeat

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I came across following two problems:

> **(1)** How many 5-digit numbers can be formed from the integers 1,2,…,9 with only one digit appearing twice?
>
> **(2)** How many 5-digit numbers can be formed from the integers 1,2,…,9 with two digits appearing twice?

I solved (1) as follows:

> **(A):** ${}^9P_5/2!=7560$
> Since we have to permute 5 digits out of 9, out of which 2 are same.

But the given asnwer was:

> **(B):** $9\times\binom{5}{2}\times 8\times 7\times 6=30240$
> Since any one of 9 digits may repeat twice, out of 5 positions, 2 will be occupied by that digit. Number of ways to select these two positions = $\binom{5}{2}$ In remaining 3 positions, we have to put remaining digits which can be done in $8\times 7\times 8$ ways.

Then I tried solving (2) by approach (B):

> **(C):** $9\times\binom{5}{2}\times 8\times \binom{3}{2} \times \frac{7}{2}=7560$
> Devide by 2 follows because we count 33445 twice, one for 3 first and another for 4 first.

The given answer was:

> **(D):** $\binom{9}{2}\times 7\times \frac{5!}{2!2!}=7560$
> We can select two digits to be repeated out of 9 in $\binom{9}{2} $ ways. The last digit can be any of remaining 7. We can permute 5 digits out of which 2 are same and another 2 are same in $\frac{5!}{2!2!}$ ways.

So I tried solving (1) by approach (D):

> **(E):**  $9\times 8\times 7\times 6\times \frac{5!}{2!}=181440$

Now I am severely confused.
I have following doubts:

**D1:**  Why (A) is giving same value as (C) and (D)? Is (A) is third approach to solve (2) (first two approaches being (C) and (D)) instead of (1)? Or its just coincidence that (A) == (C) == (D)

**D2:** Why value of (E) (which follows approach of (D)) is not same as (B)?

Comment: I cannot detect a difference between $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: both question are same

Comment: my bad, fixed (2)

Comment: D2: "Why value of (E) is not same as (B)?"  When doing $9\times 8\times 7\times 6$ you have applied some sort of significance and order to the digits that you selected.  For example, $9$ ways to pick the furthest left digit, $8$ ways to pick the next appearing digit, $7$ ways to pick the second to last digit and $6$ ways to pick the last digit.  Then with $\frac{5!}{2!}$ you are rearranging these further.  The $\frac{5!}{2!}$ term would have been if you hadn't yet come up with an order in which to place these, but since you picked the order at the time of picking the digit, you overcounted.

Comment: Correcting your approach for (E), we pick which digit was repeated in $9$ ways.  We then simultaneously and without order pick which three additional digits are used in $\binom{8}{3}$ ways.  We then arrange these digits, noting two of them are the same, in $\frac{5!}{2!}$ ways.  This gives $9\times \binom{8}{3}\times \frac{5!}{2!}$ which if you notice is equal to exactly what we got before, $30240$.  Again, your mistake was picking the remaining digits where order incorrectly mattered, instead of picking them where order didn't matter since we account for the order later.

Comment: Very satisfying analysis. Anything about D1?

Comment: Also I was thinking, for (1), whether we should the consider case with one digit repeating twice and another one thrice a valid case?

Comment: In (1), if we allow one digit to repeat twice and another thrice, then by approach (C), we get $9\times \binom{5}{2}\times 8\times 7\times 6+9\times\binom{5}{2}\times 8$ and by approach (D) we get, $9\times \binom{8}{3}\times\frac{5!}{2!}+9\times 8\times \frac{5!}{2!3!}$. Both give 30960. I hope I am correct here. Someone please confirm if they get time.